# How does the number of files in a directory affect performance?

Tags: performance, filesystems

I did a bit of googling on this as I was sure this question must have been answered, but I found nothing concise. I realize that it depends very much on the type of filesystem used. But are there any general statements one can make?

Is it generally faster to have, say, 10.000 files in a single folder, or 100 folders containing 100 files each?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on context, and what you're trying to do with those files. I usually keep my Windows folders below 4k files (4096), because Explorer tends to bog down when displaying them.

However, in *nix based OS'es, I've had 10k+ files in a folder with no discernable performance loss, given I knew what files I was looking for.

Obviously, if you're going to do any iterating through a folder, which is an O(n) operation, it will take longer the more files you have.

Answer (score 1):

It's faster to the operating system reach the file when you have 100 folders with 100 files inside, I see a lot of improvement when I split one directory that had more than 20.000 files inside.